# Failed to reallocate account data

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, rust, pda

I want to create a PDA account to store data about participants' wallet addresses and their deposit amounts. I have used a PDA account to store this information. It works fine when I set the array size to 100, but I encounter an error when I try to set a larger array size. I have sufficient funds to cover the rent, but I am still facing this error when creating the PDA.

```
impl AllParticipants {
    pub const MAX: usize = 500;
    // Discriminator + Vec + (PubKey + u64) * Donators Amount
    pub const SIZE: usize = 8 + 4 + (32 + 8) * AllParticipants::MAX;

    pub fn binary_search<T: Ord>(
        sorted_vec: &[T],
        target: T,
    ) -> std::result::Result<usize, anchor_lang::error::Error> {
        let mut low = 0;
        let mut high = sorted_vec.len();

        while low < high {
            let mid = (low + high) / 2;
            match sorted_vec[mid].cmp(&target) {
                std::cmp::Ordering::Less => low = mid + 1,
                std::cmp::Ordering::Equal => return Ok(mid),
                std::cmp::Ordering::Greater => high = mid,
            }
        }
        return Err(ProgramError::Custom(99).into());
    }
}

`
**Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Failed to reallocate account data**
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only reallocate up to `1024 * 10` bytes per instruction: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/70107e2196c12ef46d73788c55502ffd3fe2080e/sdk/program/src/entrypoint.rs#L263

This account size grows to more than 20KB, so you're likely running into this limit.

If you need to make the account that big, you'll need to do it in 10KB increments over multiple transactions. You might even be able to do it in different instructions in the same transaction, but I can't remember if the limit is at the top-level instruction or transaction.

Comment: I have taken almost 100 addresses as an array, so if I want to take more than 100, is there anything else we can use for this?

Comment: You can also avoid using a PDA and just allocate a very large account from the start

Comment: thanks for reply - How can I do this? can you please share the method?

Comment: Certainly, you can call `system_instruction::create_account` and pass up to 10 million as the size, for 10MB: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/cdc284189a042b7a4e2c44b99c2bc36da7566524/sdk/program/src/system_instruction.rs#L436